# Analysis in a beta simulation

Tags: r, beta-distribution

I did a simulation where shape1=1 and shape2=2, for n=10, n=100 and n=1000, the following is:

```
beta1 <- 1
beta2 <- 2
n<-10
asim<-1000
xbar<-rep(NA,asim)
xbar2<-rep(NA,asim)
xbar3<-rep(NA,asim)
xvar<-rep(NA,asim)
xvar2<-rep(NA,asim)
xvar3<-rep(NA,asim)
for(i in 1:asim){
  set.seed(1+i)
  x<-rbeta(n,beta1,beta2)
  x2<-rbeta(n*10,beta1,beta2)
  x3<-rbeta(n*100,beta1,beta2)
  xbar[i]<-mean(x)
  xbar2[i]<-mean(x2)
  xbar3[i]<-mean(x3)
  xvar[i]<-var(x)
  xvar2[i]<-var(x2)
  xvar3[i]<-var(x3)
}

cbind(mean(xbar),mean(xbar2),mean(xbar3))
cbind(var(xbar),var(xbar2),var(xbar3))        

 [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3336623 0.3328817 0.3328281
            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 0.005746904 0.0005396724 5.389877e-05
```

I was asked to compare the sample mean and variances, and to explain what should I find in each "n".
What I can see is that all the means are similar and the variances reduce if the n increases, is this because of the central limit theorem?

What other conclusions can I get with this? I mean, before doing the simulation, what should I expect about the mean and variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about visualising this:

```
n <- c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)
tests <- lapply(n, function(i){
  output <- replicate(100, rbeta(i, beta1, beta2))
  mu <- apply(output, 2, mean)
  sd <- apply(output, 2, sd)
  out <- data.frame(n=i, mu=mu, sd=sd)
  return(out)
})

data <- do.call(rbind, tests)
boxplot(sd~n, data=data)
boxplot(mu~n, data=data)
```

The Mean and Standard Deviation will converge to the same value, as your `rbeta` is drawing from the same family, the same distribution.

The variability of the mean & standard deviation from repetitions will reduce, the more draws we take from the distribution (n). This makes sense if you think in extreme cases. If you take 2 values, they are any 2 values from the family, and so you can see more variability. If you take 1 million values, and then take another 1 million values, it will look like the population its drawn from. Make sense?